# Class Helper and Class Interceptor in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a piece of code as shown bellow :

Interface section :

```
TControlOrganizer = class(TComponent)  // a kind of List of TControl
private
  FList : TList;  //Handling list of TControl
  ..............
end;

TControlHelperAdd = class // Just for separating value entered by user and value produced by code
  private
    FOrganizer : TControlOrganizer;
    FOrigValue : String;
    FUserValue : String;
end;

TControlHelper = class helper for TControl  //Basic helper for TControl
  private
    class var
      FAddProp : TControlHelperAdd;
  protected
    procedure SetOrganizer(Value : TControlOrganizer);
    function getOrganizer:TControlOrganizer;
  public
    class Constructor doinit;
    class Destructor deinit;
    procedure OrganizerChanged;virtual;
  published
    Property Organizer:TControlOrganizer read getOrganizer write setOrganizer; //Problem No.1
  end;

//Helper for CustomEdit inherited from TControlHelper
TCustomEditHelper = class helper(TControlHelper) for TCustomEdit
  protected
    procedure OrganizerChanged;override;
  end;
//TEdit : interceptor
TEdit= class(StdCtrls.TEdit)
  protected
    procedure Change;override;  //problem No.3
end;
```

implementation section :

```
{TControlHelper}

class Constructor TControlHelper.doinit;
begin
  FAddProp :=TControlHelperAdd.Create;
end;

class Destructor TControlHelper.deinit;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FAddProp);
end;

procedure TControlHelper.OrganizerChanged;
begin
end;

procedure TControlHelper.SetOrganizer(Value : TControlOrganizer);
begin
  if FAddProp.FOrganizer<>value then begin
     if assigned(FAddProp.FOrganizer) then begin
       FAddProp.FOrganizer.remove(self);
     end;
     FAddProp.FOrganizer:=value;
     if assigned(FAddProp.FOrganizer) then begin
       FAddProp.FOrganizer.Add(self);
     end;
     OrganizerChanged;  //Problem No.2
  end;
end;

function TControlHelper.getOrganizer:TControlOrganizer;
begin
  result:=FAddProp.FOrganizer;
end;

{TCustomEditHelper}
procedure TCustomEditHelper.OrganizerChanged; //problem No.2
begin
  if assigned(FAddProp) then begin
    if assigned(Organizer) then begin
      FAddProp.FOrigValue:=Text;
      FAddProp.FUserValue:=Text;
    end;
  end;
end;

{TEdit = Interceptor} 
procedure TEdit.Change; //Problem No.3
begin
  inherited Change;
  FAddProp.FUserValue:=Text;
end;
```

I found 3 problems that i couldn't solve myself.

Problem 1 : 
Published property property does not show up in the Object Inspector. I think I made a mistake and forgot something here.

problem 2 :
overridden method from class helper as shown above didn't fire (didn't work).

problem 3 :
overridden method from interceptor class as shown above didn't fire (didn't work).

Could anyone please help me find out what's wrong with that?
Thanks for help and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Sorry for not too clear. Problem 1 : the published property didn't show up on inspector. Problem 2 : does it mean helpers don't allow inheritance especially overriding method? Problem 3 : does it mean i prefer create new class derived from TEdit than instantiating interceptor?

Comment: Did you know, that FAddProp is global unique to all related instances and not unique per instance because it is a class field? It seems to be useless in this use case

Comment: Thanks. You are right. FAddProp is a global unit. I found some docs form delphi.about.com for better using interceptor than of helper.

Comment: Before using interceptors i would think about adapters because of less sideeffects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Problem 1**

> A published property in a helper does not show up in the Object Inspector.

That's right. Properties declared in helpers will never appear in the Object Inspector.

**Problem 2**

> Virtual methods have no effect in class helpers.

Again, that's by design. Although the compiler allows you to define virtual methods in helpers, it doesn't have any effect. In order for `TCustomEditHelper.OrganizerChanged` to fire, `TCustomEditHelper` needs to be the active helper for the target object.

**Problem 3**

> The `Change` method for my intercepted `TEdit` class does not fire.

That's because you are not instantiating the intercepted `TEdit`. If you instantiate the right class, the interceptor class that you define, that method will fire.

Comment: Problem 3 solved just by put the interceptor unit name after stdctrls in "uses". Problem 1 and 2 is solved by using inherited class. The helper class is just to help add some simple methods.

Comment: @David Heffernan wouldn't the published property from the helper appear in the object inspector if we Register the helper class to using registercomponents ? is there a way to make the property appear in the oi?

Answer (score 4):

A helper class can be thought of a regular non-object oriented function that accepts the object as its first parameter. Helpers let you hide this and code as if you were calling methods.  If you see them as simple functions then you can see why they don't show up in the object inspector or anywhere where access to the objects internals are used (like virtual method tables, dispatch methods, and published properties) because there are no internal changes to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Such a decision suggests itself.

```
TControlHelper = class helper for TControl
private
    function GetTest: Integer;
protected
    property Test: Integer read GetTest;
end;

TMyThing = class(TControl)
published
    property Test;
end;
```

You will see the Test in designtime property.
However, when compiling a real project, we get
[dcc32 Fatal Error] F2084 Internal Error: AV0A967995(0A8F0000)-R00000000-0

Comment: However, I found a solution.
TControlHelper = class helper for TControl
protected
function GetTest: Integer;
end;

TMyThing = class (TControl)
published
property Test: Integer read GetTest;
end;

The Integer type is conditional here, it may be the class you need,
an instance of which TControlHelper will cut to you from, for example,
Spring.Services.ServiceLocator by creating it on first call. The key will be Self

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify. Code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

However, I found a solution.

```pascal
TControlHelper = class helper for TControl
protected
function GetTest: Integer;
end;

TMyThing = class (TControl)
published
property Test: Integer read GetTest;
end;
```

The Integer type is conditional here, it may be the class you need,
an instance of which `TControlHelper` will cut to you from, for example,
`Spring.Services.ServiceLocator` by creating it on first call. The key will be Self